# Оператор Where IN mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть массив из id пользователей.
скажем такой: `$arr_id = array(90, 90, 92);`
хочу сделать один запроса на с помощью **where in**, но так как в массиве имеется два значения одинаковых - запрос выдает результат в виде двух строк, а нужно в виде трех.

Это принципиально.

Как быть, не хочется делать отдельные запросы для каждого из значения в массиве, потому как их может быть очень много.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите на каждое значение из списка иметь строку, используйте подзапрос-конструктор типа:

```
select * from table d
join (select 90 id union all select 90 union all select 92) x
on d.id = x.id
```

Answer (score -2):

Напишите хоть 10 одинаковых чисел в условии WHERE IN, вы все равно получите "уникальное" кол-во строк. Если вы даже сделаете кучу "отдельных" запросов, в результате вам SQL сервер выведет одну и ту же строку.

Comment: это я понимаю. поэтому спрашиваю решение другое